# ros_control spaces

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently trying to get my head around ros_control. And I am not sure I fully understand the example given in the overview of [ros_control's wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), the example is show in this image:

[image description http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=gazebo_ros_control.png](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=gazebo_ros_control.png)

This example actually shows 2 PID:

- one in the real robot: *PID loop to follow effort setpoint*, in a grey box
- one in a joint_position_controller : *PID Controller*, in a yellow box

What I understand is that the grey PID is a low-level **current control** and the yellow PID is a low-level **torque control**. This is better seen on the block diagram below, which is my understanding of the way things work.

[image: image description]

Now in order to get to know more about it I have checked the code for **EffortJointInterface** in [this source file](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/hardware_interface/html/c++/joint__command__interface_8h_source.html). It turns out **EffortJointInterface** derives from **JointCommandInterface**. These classes are nearly empty.

Hence my questions:

- can someone confirm my block diagram is right?
- what is **EffortJointInterface** doing if there is nothing inside the class?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187579/ros_control-spaces/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-01-23**:
Is this question still valid or can it be closed?. Since it was asked many interactions have taken place in the robot control SIG.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2015-01-23**:
Question now answered below. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check [Adolfo Rodriguez's RosCon 2014 lecture](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ros_control_an_overview.pdf), it gives interesting insight and much more detail on the above.

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1